# How to get next/previous record in MySQL & asp.net (using c#)?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

How to get next/previous record in MySQL & asp.net??? .  am developing a web form it's include vouchers in each voucher there are a unique serial number , I need to add next and previous button to retrieve the next and previous serial with serial information , for example am in serial number 26 if I pressed in next button it will return serial 27 and if I pressed in previous button it must return serial 25

my code :

```
protected void BtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[4];
    para[0] = new SqlParameter("@v_serial", TxtVoucherNo.Text);
    para[1] = new SqlParameter("@v_branch", DDLBranch.SelectedValue);
    para[2] = new SqlParameter("@v_trans_code", DDLTransCode.SelectedValue);
    para[3] = new SqlParameter("@v_date", db.getDate(TxtDate.Text));
    DataTable dtExist = db.SelectCmdText("Select * from voucher where v_serial=(@v_serial +1 ) and v_trans_code=@v_trans_code and v_branch=@v_branch  ", para);
    TxtVoucherNo.Text = dtExist.Rows[0]["v_serial"].ToString(); ;
    GridView1.DataSource = dtExist;
    TxtDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dtExist.Rows[0]["v_date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Show your code so we have something to build off of instead of creating an entirely unrelated demo.

Comment: "Previous" and "Next" - **ordered by what** ?? If you want to have navigation, you have to have some ordering criteria